# splash screen shown as blank screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

I made a splash layout, that last for a time and then other activity should be loaded,alone it works perfectly, but when it's connected to other activity, it shows blank screen.

`mainifest` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="andy.propaganda"
    android:installLocation="auto" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/my_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".shit"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.coderefer.androidsplashscreenexample.MAINACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`splash` activity :

```
package andy.propaganda;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by Andrew on 2/4/2016.
 */
public class Splash extends Activity {

    //welcome animation
    ImageView loading_img;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        loading_img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.loading_view);
        final Animation animatable = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.welcome_screen_anim);
        loading_img.setAnimation(animatable);

//
        for(int i = 0;i< 100000000;i++);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, shit.class);
        intent.putExtra("jhjh", 8);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

`main` activity :

```
package andy.propaganda;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * Created by Andrew on 2/5/2016.
 */
public class shit extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

`splash.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/MyBlue"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/my_launcher"
        android:paddingTop="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/loading"
        android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
        android:id="@+id/loading_view"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="loading your files"
        android:id="@+id/welcome_message"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="#010101"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_bar_progress_bar_size"
        android:layout_above="@+id/loading_view"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove this line  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.coderefer.androidsplashscreenexample.MAINACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter> from your **Shit** manifest activity

Comment: I tried it, but there is no difference

Comment: remove for loop and instead of that use Handler your code seems Ok :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use timer on splash screen instead of `for(int i = 0;i< 100000000;i++);` which will wait for some time suppose 5 sec and than load another Activity.

```
package andy.propaganda;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by Andrew on 2/4/2016.
 */
public class Splash extends Activity {

    //welcome animation
    ImageView loading_img;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        loading_img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.loading_view);
        final Animation animatable = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.welcome_screen_anim);
        loading_img.setAnimation(animatable);



     new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your task
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, shit.class);
        intent.putExtra("jhjh", 8);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
   }, 5000);

    }

}
```

Comment: it worked perfectly, but what in case that i need to perform a specific task and send it as a parameter to the next activity, in my case i want to search the full device to load all the mps files in array and send it to the next activity ?

Comment: The schedule(TimerTask task,long delay,) method is used to schedule the specified task for execution, beginning after the specified delay. You can define your task within run method.

Answer (score 1):

First of All dont use for Loop for waiting time instead of That use **Handler** with something like this :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, shit.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }, 500);
```

Then remove this line from your manifest.xml :

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Rest of your code seems ok :)

Also take look at [this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) link which well-explained about **Splash Screen**.

Answer (score 1):

RxJava solution:

```
Observable.empty().subscribeOn(AndroidSchadelurs.mainThread()).delay(500, TimeUtils.MILISECONDS).subscribe(this::startActivity(this, new Intent));
```